# mongoose: disallow updating of specific fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var post = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    _createdOn: Date
});
```

I want to allow setting the `_createdOn` field only upon document creation, and disallow changing it on future updates. How is it done in Mongoose?

Comment: See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I achieved this effect by setting the `_createdOn` in the schema's pre-save hook (only upon first save):

```js
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (!this._createdOn) {
        this._createdOn = new Date();
    }
    next();
});
```

... and disallowing changes from anywhere else:

```js
userSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
    if (this.isModified('_createdOn')) {
        this.invalidate('_createdOn');
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63917295/6613333

You can make the field as immutable.

```
var post = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    _createdOn: { type: Date, immutable: true }
});
```