# Prevent field from being updated after initial set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose or the plain MongoDB driver, is there a way to lock a field from being updated after that field is first set?

Comment: Why can't you just not overwrite that property?

Comment: Our business logic dictates that the first value is the correct one. Any changes to that value are to be ignored; but we can update other fields in the document, just not that particular field. It's sort of like the _id field, after all.

Comment: Just never change it throughout the software you are writing? (you can ensure this business logic in the tests wrapping the update operations. also If you're always using the update operators and not doing blanket document replaces (which you shouldn't do) then you'll be fine.

Comment: doing this at the application level is kind of a pain. The problem is if I write an update query, such as `Model.update(condition, data, options, cb)`, then I can't prevent changing the field for a pre-existing document.

Comment: Note that my question, is pretty similar to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824657/how-do-i-update-mongodb-document-fields-only-if-they-dont-exist

Comment: This question is basically the other side of the same coin as the question I just linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @eagor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342081/mongoose-disallow-updating-of-specific-fields).

I achieved this effect by setting the `_createdOn` in the schema's pre save hook (only upon first save):

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this._createdOn) {
        this._createdOn = new Date();
    }
    next();
});
```

... and disallowing changes from anywhere else:

```
userSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (self.isModified('_createdOn')) {
        self.invalidate('_createdOn');
    }
});
```